# get values on popup in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a popup ,on Popup I have checkboxes with same name.When we click on the button

I need to get the selected checkboxes.

popup

```
<div class="form">
    <ul class="lists">
        <li>
            <div class="ui-checkbox">
                <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off" for="int1">test</label>
                <input id="int1" name="result" value="CPmiyS6vXv3RHPpTGW81" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="ui-checkbox">
                <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off" for="int2">test1</label>
                <input id="int2" name="result" value="5JCHGPLRrDemmqlfOGEJ" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="ui-checkbox">
                <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off" for="int3">test21</label>
                <input id="int3" name="result" value="5R4OVDmAHL86LvwbkOWO" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input class="createName" name="name" placeholder="Create Name" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div>
            <div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
                Add to Names
                <input value="Add Name" title="Add to Name" name="submit" class="major popup_add_to_name" type="submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="link ui-link" data-rel="back">cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code

```
$(".popup_add_to_name").on("click", function(e) {


        $("#productForm input[name=name]").val($("#form input[name=name]:checked").val());
        var form = $("#productForm");
         $.ajax({
                url: '/name/list/add',
                type: 'post',
                data: form.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,
                timeout: 5000,
                success : displayAddItemsToList
         });
    });
```

in jquery I am trying to get the value of selected checkbox value to input hidden place which is inside the form.

But I am not able to get the value of selected checkbox on popup.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with what you have posted.

For one, isn't going to work:

```
$("#productForm input[name=name]").val($("#form input[name=name]:checked").val());
```

It says, find the input whose name is name within the element that has an id of productForm and set its value to the value of the input with a name that is name that is within the element with an id of form.  That could be ok if you have an element productForm with an input named name somewhere else that you haven't shown in your html above EXCEPT then you have the checked attribute in your selector and your `#form input[name=name]` is not a checkbox so it will never have a checked attribute.

You have some problems elsewhere in your markup too.  The checkboxes all have the same name.  They should be unique if they are checkboxes (such that you can choose one or more items).  Then you should be able to just serialize your form, but currently you are trying to serialize the data in some element with an id of productform.  In the html you posted there is no element with an id of product form.

Plus, I suspect there might be some challenges in your ajax call too.  Are you sure you're wanting a crossDomain call?  And, I'm guessing that the success function might need some data passed to it, such as which items to add to the list to display (just a guess based on the name).

Maybe you can post your #productForm and explain a little more what you need to do?